# Can't save a child class from a generic parent in a variable with parent class using an interface as generic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I am trying to make an inventory system where you can easily add new weapon types. by just making a child from the class ToolInformation and enter the Attacksystem it needs to use.

But I can't save the child class(`MeleeWeaponInformation<MeleeAttack>`) in a variable `ToolInformation<IAttack>`

Does anyone know a way to make this idea work?

ERROR: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MeleeWeaponInformation' to 'ToolInformation'

Generic class

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New tool", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Tool")]
public class ToolInformation<T> : ItemInformation where T : IAttack
{
    public T GetComponent(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        return gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
    }
}
```

Child Class

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New melee weapon", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Melee weapon")]
public class MeleeWeaponInformation : ToolInformation<MeleeAttack>
{
}
```

Trying to save it in a variable like this

```
ToolInformation<IAttack> tool = (MeleeWeaponInformation)inventory.items[i].information;
if (tool)
{
    selectedTool = tool;
    playerController.attack += selectedTool.GetComponent(playerController.gameObject).AttackCall;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way to get the same result that I wanted, but thanks for the help.

My solution:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New tool", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Tool")]
public abstract class ToolInformation : ItemInformation
{
    public abstract IAttack EnableTool(GameObject gameObject);
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New melee weapon", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Melee weapon")]
public class MeleeWeaponInformation : ToolInformation
{
    []public float damage = 1;

    public override IAttack EnableTool(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        return gameObject.GetComponent<MeleeAttack>();
    }
}

ToolInformation tool = (MeleeWeaponInformation)inventory.items[i].information;
if (tool)
{
    Debug.LogError("Tool Selected");
    selectedTool = tool;
    playerController.attack += selectedTool.EnableTool(playerController.gameObject).AttackCall;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do as bellow:

```
ItemInformation item = new MeleeWeaponInformation();
```

And add

```
public IAttack GetComponent(GameObject gameObject)
```

to the ItemInformation.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New tool", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Tool")]
public class ToolInformation<T> : ItemInformation where T : IAttack
{
    public T GetComponent(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        return gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
    }

    IAttack ItemInformation.GetComponent(GameObject gameObject)
        => GetComponent(GameObject gameObject);

}
```